# PhotoSwipe in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, photoswipe

I'm trying to use [PhotoSwipe](http://photoswipe.com/documentation/getting-started.html) in ReactJs component, and it doesn't work.

In sake of simplicity:

I've took all the html from [here](http://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/ZYbPJM) and put it into render in react component.
All the js i've put into `ComponentDidMount` method.

I'm pushing on the image caption and getting `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` on `gallery.init();`
All `class` changed to `className` as well as all `itemScope, itemType, itemProp, tabIndex` 
What is wrong?

Comment: need more information like a stack trace or even better a JSFiddle or similar with a reproduction

Answer (score 0):

In  react you have to build component before you can do 'ComponentDidMount'. So render your html in a react component. like this :

```
var something = React.createClass ({

  render : function () {
      return(
          <div>
              //Your html code here
          </div>
      )
   }
});
```

After that you can work with the something component.